# Working with templates

Tags: c++, temp

Im currently studying c++ templates and there's something I don't understand. So far I understand if you have the following generic class

```
    template <class T> class A{
        ...
    }
```

To provide a specific specialization of the class, say for `int` objects, you'd define the following:

```
    template<> class A<int>{
        ...
    }
```

However, I have been seeing cases similar to the following:

Original class is,

```
    template <class T, int Size> class buffer{
        ...
    }
```

Then the speciliazed class for objects of type `int` is,

```
    template <int Size> class buffer<int, Size>{
        ...
    }
```

I'm confused as why the specilization for `int` is not the following:

```
    template<> class bufffer<int, int Size>{
        ...
    }
```

Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `buffer` template has two template parameters. The first is a type parameter because it begins with `class`, and the second is a non-type parameter because it begins with `int`.

What you are seeing is a partial specialization on only the first parameter. Note that the template arguments for a template specialization are totally independent of the template arguments for the original template (this is one of the major things that confused me when I was learning this). For example, it would work just as well as:

```
template <int N> class buffer<int, N> { ... };
```

It is basically giving a specialization for when the first template argument of `buffer` is the type `int` and the second is some `int` value.

Whenever you start with `template <>` (empty brackets), that is an explicit specialization where you are specifying *all* of the template arguments. For example, you could do:

```
template <> class buffer<int, 1> { ... };
```

This would be a specialization for when the first template argument is the `int` type and the second is the value `1`.